# Prevent ggplot smoothing whole data series?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some fluorescence spectrometry data that has rather 'spiky' and hard-to-visualise lines on my `ggplot` graph. I've decided that using `ggplot`'s smoothing function tidies up my data quite nicely, however it has stopped my data all originating from the same point on the ordinate (and thus looks a bit odd).

The before and after of the 2 plots are here:

[image: Natural data]

[image: Smoothed data]

I'm mainly bothered by the cyan line, (which I suspect is an experimental outlier anyway), though ideally they all need to originate as they do in the first image.

**Specifically therefore,** my question is can I force `ggplot`'s smooth function to ignore, for instance, the first 10 datapoints? Or an equally valid alternative would be to force `ggplot` to take its smoothing lines from an ordinate value assigned by me?

If anyone thinks they have a more elegant solution than either of the above I'm all ears.

MWE:

```
# Define easy y value handles for plotting.
# Controls:
Con1 = WT.MeOH
Con2 = Adj..WT.Tunicamycin
Con3 = Adj..F288W.Tunicamycin
# Epeptides:
Epep37 = Adj..Epep.37ug.Avg
Epep62 = Adj..Epep.62ug.Avg
Epep83 = Adj..Epep.83ug.Avg
# RWGLW Pentapeptides:
PP166 = Adj..RWGLW.166ug.Avg
PP416 = Adj..RWGLW.416ug.Avg
PP624 = Adj..RWGLW.624ug.Avg
# GW-Octanol Dipeptides:
DP83 = Adj..GW.Oct.83ug.Avg
DP166 = Adj..GW.Oct.166ug.Avg
DP416 = Adj..GW.Oct.416ug.Avg

# Defining dataframes
fludata <- data.frame(Secs, Con1, Con2, Con3, Epep37, 
                  Epep62, Epep83, PP166, PP416, PP624,
                  DP83, DP166, DP416)

# Each of the following corresponds to a data series in my fluorimetry dataset. 
# The string in the colour field is for ease of generating the legend.
s <- ggplot(fludata, aes(Secs))
s <- s  + geom_smooth(data=fludata[11:nrow(fludata),], aes(y=Con1, colour="WT MeOH PTC"))
s <- s  + geom_smooth(data=fludata[11:nrow(fludata),], aes(y=Con2, colour="WT Tunicamycin [83] NTC"))
s <- s  + geom_smooth(data=fludata[11:nrow(fludata),], aes(y=Con3, colour="F288W Tunicamycin [83] NTC"))
s <- s  + geom_smooth(data=fludata[11:nrow(fludata),], aes(y=Epep37, colour="F288W E-peptide [37]"))
s <- s  + geom_smooth(data=fludata[11:nrow(fludata),], aes(y=Epep62, colour="F288W E-peptide [62]"))
s <- s  + geom_smooth(data=fludata[11:nrow(fludata),], aes(y=Epep83, colour="F288W E-peptide [83]"))
s <- s  + geom_smooth(data=fludata[11:nrow(fludata),], aes(y=PP166, colour="F288W RWGLW [166]"))
s <- s  + geom_smooth(data=fludata[11:nrow(fludata),], aes(y=PP416, colour="F288W RWGLW [416]"))
s <- s  + geom_smooth(data=fludata[11:nrow(fludata),], aes(y=PP624, colour="F288W RWGLW [624]"))
s <- s  + geom_smooth(data=fludata[11:nrow(fludata),], aes(y=DP83, colour="F288W GW-Oct [83]"))
s <- s  + geom_smooth(data=fludata[11:nrow(fludata),], aes(y=DP166, colour="F288W GW-Oct [166]"))
s <- s  + geom_smooth(data=fludata[11:nrow(fludata),], aes(y=DP416, colour="F288W GW-Oct [416]"))
# Axis labels
s <- s + ylab("Intensity") + xlab("Time (seconds)")
# Legend options
s <- s + theme(legend.position=c(.15,0.85), legend.title=element_blank())
```

The above code will produce a graph, but not omitting the first 10 data points as is the idea.

@Ben Bolker, I haven't shown your code here as I've not tested it yet.

Since I've not really done this for R before, the easiest option I could think of was to provide my downloadable csv:

I redefined some of my poorly named data series too so I updated the MWE.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz_H3y-7pX9FcHNSZUZWeVRuVnc/edit?usp=sharing

Don't really have any more details to give!

Comment: this might be hard to do entirely within `ggplot2`, as it smooths every line separately.  If you are willing to set the intercept *a priori* you could try something like `library(mgcv); ggplot(...)+geom_smooth(method="gam",formula=y~offset(100)+s(x))` (you may want something like `s(x,k=50)` if the results are significantly more smoothed than you want).  I don't think you can achieve the same level of control with the default loess method ...

Comment: Possibly I'm missing something, but I get an error doing that: `Error in model.frame.default(formula = y ~ offset(100) + x, data = data,  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'offset(100)')`
... THe line that generates it was `geom_smooth(aes(y=Con1, colour="WT MeOH PTC"), method="gam", formula=y~offset(100)+s(x))`

Comment: the offset isn't automatically recycled to the length of the data. One thing to try (a little hard without a MWE ...); (1) `y~offset(rep(100,nrow(mydata)))+s(x)`

Comment: thanks for adding a MWE, but it's not really reproducible since we don't have your data set (or a smaller/simulated data set with similar structure ...) have you looked at http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000 ?

Comment: Yeah I did wonder about that. I imagine it would be easiest to give you guys my data set than try and make one that resembles it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can I force ggplot's smooth function to ignore, for instance, the first 10 datapoints

Sure. If the data is in `your_df`:

```
ggplot() + 
  # plot geom_smooth for just the 11th data point onward
  geom_smooth(data=your_df[11:nrow(your_df),], aes(...)) +

  # optionally, plot the jagged series for first ten lines
  geom_line(data=your_df[1:10,], aes(...))
```

Comment: Edited my answer with a MWE. I must have misinterpreted something I guess, because that code seems to have no effect.

Comment: So after playing with a much smaller example, I think I worked out why I wasnt seeing anything. Because the data series' are so large, not plotting 11 on a large axis of ~800 meant I just couldnt see it. 

Doesn't quite solve my problem though, as ill need to play with the smoothed curve to find a good point to allow both lines to appear joined. Strikes me as a bit of a trial-and-error bodge-job though.

Comment: Yeah, i was just responding to the question as originally stated ('can I force ggplot's smooth function to ignore, for instance, the first 10 datapoints'). Without posting your data (or some similar dummy data), there's not much else I can suggest. Have you tried a simple moving average? Or if you just want a less busy-looking line, select every n-th data point and just plot those, connected with straight lines.